# Decreasing reputation by more than 1.1K at once

Tags: support, reputation

Today during several minutes my reputation was decreased by more than 1.1k with the reason that "serial voting was reversed".

However neither today nor yesterday neither this month or the month before I did not observe any "serial voting" of my answers.

So this looks at least very strange.

I could understand if during a day some person can up-vote my answers. However the last week I answered questions very rare. And it would be seen at once.

However I see that sometimes I down-voted even by -20 by the reason. So there should be many persons who serially up-voted my answers. And moreover it can be done for example during a month. I do not think that somebody will up-vote specially my answers for example one hundred times per month. I am not even saying "per week".:)

Thus it does not resemble that my reputation was decreased at once during several minutes by more than 1.1K points due to "serial voting".

I found one my answer that is dated by **answered Feb 27 '15 at 13:48** that was down-voted by the reason. So it will be reasonable to ask is up-voting with a period equal to a year and a half is considered as serial up-voting?:)

It is interesting who is that moderator who decreased my reputation by 1.1K at once?

After reading the answer of **@Shog9♦**  I am sure that it was done intentionally. He wrote in his answer

> Also, please stop serial voting

however neither serial voting was done by me at least these months.

Comment: No moderator was responsible for this. Moderators cannot invalidate votes, only SE employees and automated vote-invalidation scripts can do that.

Answer (score 39):

I'm currently working through a very large backlog of serial voting reports, stretching back over a year and covering both Q&A and Documentation. Due to some deficiencies in the current automated system, anomalous voting occasionally slips through the cracks and piles up in my inbox; I'm trying to clear that out before yet another new year begins.

Checking [your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow?tab=reputation) for today, it appears you've been on the giving *and* receiving end of quite a bit of serial voting, both up and down. These votes go back in some cases nearly three years.

I apologize for the disruption; we're working on building these checks into the automated system in the near future, which'll greatly reduce the amount of work for me and frustration for folks like yourself.

Also, please stop serial voting.

#### See also: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15317/exchange-votes-or-favours/15520#15520

(yes, 6 months back; I said it was a long backlog)

Comment: So, it's spr... err... winter cleaning time?

Comment: @Shog9♦  I have not understood why you pointed out this reference and how is it related with my question?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - The link is just additional backstory on when and why there's an additional query being used to detect serial voting.

Comment: @BSMP This link has nothing common with my question. It is not the first time when my reputation is decreased even without any notification. Just today the decreasing was huge and it appeared in the history of my reputation, Early it was done silently.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - The link is more information on *this answer*.

Comment: @BSMP There is no information relative my question. The only information relative to my question is contained in this answer: it was done intentionally. There is no any doubts. As I said early it was done silently. Today it was decided to do this explicitly. That's all.

Comment: I mean, you're not wrong... if your votes were invalidated by accident, *then* I'd be concerned.

Comment: I saw pretty much the exact change that Vlad did. Are you also accusing me of serial voting? Or just on the receiving end of it? I would wager that higher rep users like Vlad in general saw even more drastic changes.

Comment: If you lost rep, you were on the receiving end, @andy